# Query if related collection has any entry, but without navigational property

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008-r2, linq-to-entities

Here is a simple table example of tables in foreign-key relation:

```
Foo            Bar
-------        -------
FooId          BarId  
FooName        FooId (FK) 
               BarNumber
```

Assume that the entities are imported in a Linq to Entities context, and a navigational property `Bars` is created. I can now execute a query like this:

```
var query = context.Foos.Where(foo => foo.Bars.Any(bar => bar.BarNumber == 42));
```

It will return all `Foos` which contain at least one related `Bar` according to the specific expression.But now I'm in a special scenario where no Navigational property `Bars` exists.

I could write a manual which looks like this:

```
var query = context.Foos.Join(context.Bar
                    .Where(bar => bar.BarNumber == 42),
                    foo => foo.FooId,
                    bar => bar.FooId,
                    (foos, bars) => {
                        // What here?
                    });
```

I'm not sure if that's a correct approach and/or how to handle the result selector to get the equivalent result or even sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply reverse the query so the condition is on Bars:

```
var bars = context.Bars.Where(bar => bar.BarNumber == 42);

var query = bars.Join(context.Foos,
    bar => bar.FooId,
    foo => foo.FooId,
    (bar, foo) => foo).Distinct();
```

Edit - If you find this code clearer, you can use GroupJoin:

```
var query = foos.GroupJoin(context.Bars,
    foo => foo.FooId,
    bar => bar,
    (foo, bars) => { Foo: foo, Bars: bars })
    .Where(x.Bars.Any(b => b.BarNumber == 42));
```

Comment: OK but that means that I have to stick to a Join/Distinct combination and cannot use aggregates like "Any"?

Comment: Thanks, using first attempt now, but combined into one query: `var query = context.Bars.Where(bar => bar.BarNumber == 42).Join(context.Foos, bar => bar.FooId, foo => foo.FooId, (bar, foo) => foo).Distinct();`. I will see how good this performs. Thanks!